# Создание приложения для сайта на Android

Tags: android, веб-программирование

Для расширения своего кругозора, прошу совета и подсказок в создание приложения для Android.
Задача следующая:
Необходимо написать приложение, которое осуществляло те же функции, что и сайт. А именно:

- Вывод новостей, статей и т.п.
- Поиск по сайту
- Добавление комментариев к статьям и новостям
- Просмотр каталога с графической и текстовой информациии
- Личный кабинет пользователя
- и т.д.

По идеи тот же сайт, только работает как приложение.
Подскажите с чего начать?
Что почитать (желательно с хорошими примерами), что изучить и вообще что для этого нужно. Т.е. нужна инструкция молодого бойца:)

Answer (score 3):

Два способа. Дурной и правильный.

1. Ваше приложение лишь парсер обычного сайта. Скачиваете нужные страницы, парсите html, выводите в виде пригодном для мобильного клиента. Способ уродский и может подойти лишь для сайтов находящихся не в вашем управлении и достаточно простых (а-ля башорг и пр.). При минимальной смене дизайна сайта - переделываете приложение полностью.
2. Сайт имеет API для обращения. Т.е. наборы методов, которые получают строго формализованные запрос и возвращают лишь необходимые данные т.е. контент. Оформление делаете средствами мобильного приложения. Если API нет, делаете его или идете читать 1 пункт.

[пример API](https://vk.com/developers.php?oid=-1&p=%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_API)

Comment: Правильный и самый верный способ, который в будущем выиграет и окупит усилия - апи к сайту и интеграция с приложением(клиентом)

Answer (score 3):

Можно сделать приложение, основанное на WebWiew и взаимодействовать с ним с помощью JavaScript, почитайте [здесь](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)

Comment: Провальный способ, вспомнить хотя бы знаменитый http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12987 . И таких очень много.